# Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I followed Hyperledger fabric official tutorial to deploy my first blockchain project. However, I met the problem that I have installed my chaincode named "basic" on channel "mychannel"

```
peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile "${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem" -C mychannel -n basic --peerAddresses localhost:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles "${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt" --peerAddresses localhost:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles "${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt" -c '{"function":"InitLedger","Args":[]}'
```

and the feedback is

```
Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"make sure the `chaincode basic has been successfully defined on channel mychannel and try again: chaincode definition for 'basic' exists, but chaincode is not installed"
```

but the last step I used the coomand

```
peer lifecycle chaincode querycommitted --channelID mychannel --name basic --cafile "${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem"
```

and the feedback is

```
Committed chaincode definition for chaincode 'basic' on channel 'mychannel':
Version: 1.0, Sequence: 1, Endorsement Plugin: escc, Validation Plugin: vscc, Approvals: [Org1MSP: true, Org2MSP: true]
```

I think that means I was successful committed "basic" to the channel.
But I cannot invoking the chaincode by following tutorial's steps.

What should I do to fix the problem?

I use ubuntu 20.04. on Windows OS.
I use Mobaxterm to open WSL-Ubuntu-20.04.
Tutorial is [enter link description here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploy_chaincode.html#package-the-smart-contract) I met this problem is the first step at “Invoking the chaincode”

the step

Answer (score 0):

If the contracts were commited, you should have 2 extra docker containers on your container list. Do a docker ps command to see if contract containers exist for 7051 and 9051. If the containers do not exist for the contracts, then you do not have a working contract.

Try stopping and starting your network by running the following in the docker folder - grasping at straws here

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-couch.yaml -f docker-compose-ca.yaml -f docker-compose-test-net.yaml  stop
docker-compose -f docker-compose-couch.yaml -f docker-compose-ca.yaml -f docker-compose-test-net.yaml  start
```

If there is at least one contract container available, try a docker logs command to see if any useful output is available e.g.

```
docker logs [container Id value here]
```

Step through the contract loading procedure again, but remember to increase the sequence number and version number. You could set up some environment variables as follows

```
export CC_PACKAGE_VERSION=1
export CC_PACKAGE_SEQUENCE=1
```

and then use them on the command line as follows

```
--version $CC_PACKAGE_VERSION --sequence $CC_PACKAGE_SEQUENCE
```

By doing it that way, you can install the same contract as many times as it takes to get it working, or for amendments that might come later on.

Sometimes you will have to retrace your installation steps because it is so easy to get things wrong when working by hand. Have a look at the deployCC.sh script as well. But I would recommend that you persevere in getting things working by hand first and then use automation later on.

The output that you provided seems to indicate that everything should be correct, so I can't see what the problem is without seeing the full history from start to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Check the packageId and use localhost instead of peer0.example.com

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).